# Android: How do I get a string from xml and set it toLowerCase()?

Tags: java, android, xml, methods

**Why is `toLowerCase()` method in this class not working?**

```
private List<Accordo> filter(List<Accordo> models, String query) {
    query = query.toLowerCase();

    filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Accordo model : models) {
        final String text = model.getName().toLowerCase();
        if (text.contains(query)) {
            filteredList.add(model);
        }
    }
    return filteredList;
}
```

I get:

> Cannot Resolve method `toLowerCase()`

**Since I put my string in xml, `model.getName()` returns an int, how do I get the string and set it to lower case?**

**EDIT 2:**

this is the getter for name, as you can see it's an int because it refers to a string in my string.xml file, and Android uses int to refer to images, strings and whatsoever in xml.

```
public int getName() {return name;}
```

this is an example for a string in xml:

```
<string name="choose_client">Choose an email client: </string>
```

Comment: What type does `Accordo.getName` return? And just to confirm, you don't have your own class called String, right? You're just using the one that comes with Java?

Comment: The one who down voted, please give a reason.

Comment: @YoungMillie: Well it doesn't show enough information for us to help the OP, for one thing... that's why I voted to close. Basically, without knowing the return type of `Accordo.getName()`, we can't tell what's wrong. The code that *is* shown isn't minimal, either. Basically, at the moment, it's not a good question. I haven't downvoted *yet*, but at the moment this question isn't helpful to either the OP or any later readers.

Comment: oh I got it, I put my strings in my xml so it returns int! I need to change it to string

Comment: @JonSkeet if the question is not clear, or you need more information you are welcome to ASK, downvoting would only penalize a question which I think it's well written and useful to others. As you can see I have edited it with more information. Hope it's ok for you! Maybe now you can help me out with an answer :)

Comment: Exactly @Jon Skeet, it makes sense.

Comment: you need to ask yourself does int have a lowercase/uppercase?

Comment: @Daniele can you post the code for Accordo?

Comment: @yshavit yes I'm using the java String class

Comment: @Daniele: yshavit has already asked, and it took a long time to get any response. That's why I just voted to close. But a downvote was still reasonable - it was *not* well written and *not* useful to others without that information. (And you still haven't posted a [mcve], which would be rather more useful.) Now, if `model.getName()` returns an `int` - which is rather surprising, as names aren't usually numbers - why would you want to lower-case that anyway? Once you *have* converted it into a string (e.g. with `String.valueOf(model.getName())`, it's just going to be digits anyway...

Comment: @Sanjeev the string it refers to does. I will post my Accordo class

Comment: @Daniele: You don't need to post the complete class - just a [mcve]. It sounds like your question is *really* "How do I convert an `int` into a `String`?" which was completely different to what you actually asked...

Comment: @JonSkeet because that int refers to a String in my strings.xml, and that string does have up and lower cases

Comment: @Daniele: We have no idea what XML you're referring to, or what the number has to do with it. I think you need to take a step back and think about how your data model hangs together first...

Comment: There is a tag that says android on this question. In android you store strings in an xml which are referred to as ints in the java code. Now I need to get that int, get the string it refers to, and set that string to lower case.

Comment: Just because there's an Android tag doesn't mean we magically know any of the rest of how your code fits together. And again, your question really isn't about why `toLowerCase` doesn't work - that's obvious, because you're trying to call it on an `int`. That's the answer to all you've actually asked. It now sounds like your question should be "How can I retrieve a resource by its number in Android"?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it just by getting the resource it point to and set it to lowercase:

```
final String text = getResources().getString(model.getName()).toLowerCase();
```